# Comments database table foreignkeys vs just id

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, laravel, foreign-keys

I am working on a new project and I need to set up a database 'Comments' table.
In my project it will be possible to give comments on a 'page', on a 'post' or on a 'forum topic' or something else.
Now I am wondering what will be the best setup for my 'Comments' table in a Laravel environment considering speed and workability

Either create a table with multiple foreign keys where one key will always be filled in and the other will be NULL

---

**id(int) - comment(text) - post(FK) - topic(FK) - page(FK)**

---

or create a table with no foreign keys, but only the id and a row which indicates the type of comment like this

---

**id(int) - comment(text) - type(varchar - 'post' or 'topic') - type_id(int - the id of the 'post' or 'topic')**

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better if you take the the second approach.

If there was one more source introduced later to accept comments, the table will need modification if you follow the first approach. Also, it is possible that the same user can provide comments once again on the same topic. This way of storage (2nd approach) helps.

Fetching records will still be efficient, since be it one row (1st approach), or few rows (2nd approach), the records for a particular topic will still be very selective (and so effeccient) when compared to the total size of the table.

Answer (score 2):

For the Scalability factor, you should create a table which holds the type of the post the comment will be under, so that you can add other types of posts in the future.

So the structure of the comments table should be something like that:

id(int) - comment(text) - parent_type(int) - parent_id

parent_id(int) - parent_name(varchar)

Depending on the type, you decide whcih table you are going to make the join with.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second approach is better as it will minimize the empty cells in your table also it will be easier to query.